# Possibly Unsolvable Circle Geometry Question

Tags: geometry, circles

I was recently trying to brush up on my circle geometry when I came across the below question:

A triangle PQR is inscribed in a circle, with a point W on the arc of QR. Furthermore, WX is perpendicular to PR produced, WZ is perpendicular to PQ and WY is perpendicular to RQ.

[image]
ii) Having proven that WXRY and WYZQ are cyclic quadrilaterals prove that W, Y, Z are collinear.

I attempted it yet was unable to solve it.
However, furthermore the solutions were illogical.
I’m not sure if the question is genuinely impossible and that the creators had made a mistake (judging by the incorrect solutions) or that there is a method to working it out.

Comment: The line is called Simson line: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Since WX $\perp$ XP and WY ⊥ RQ, WXRY is cyclic. 
Then,

$\angle XYW = \angle XRW = 180 - \angle PRW\tag{1}$

Similar, since WZ $\perp$ QP and WY ⊥ RQ, WYZQ is cyclic. Then,

$\angle WYZ = 180 - \angle PQW\tag{2}$

Moreover, since RPQW is cyclic, we have $\angle PRW + \angle PQW = 180$. From (1) and (2),

$$\angle WYZ + \angle XYW = 180$$

Thus, X, Y, and Z are collinear.

Answer (score 0):

The question is correctly stated, and here is a hint:

> Connect WP, XZ, RW, XY. Notice that WXRY and XWZP are cyclic
>   quadrilaterals. Now try to find the relations between angles. Ask yourself: what
>   does it mean if WXRY and XWZP are cyclic quadrilaterals?